Looker API: Get users with specific attribute enabled
I need to get all users that have a specific attribute (pii data access) enabled. I am using python looker_sdk.
I have gotten all attributes and found the correct id.
user_attr = sdk.all_user_attributes()

Now I also want to see all users that have this attribute set to true.
I know I can check all groups that have a user with this specific attribute
sdk.all_user_attribute_group_values('25') 

but I need to get the list of users so I can start contacting them.
